# What is the role of Advanced SME in Azure Synapse Analytics?

Tags: azure-synapse

I watched a training video on Azure Synapse Analytics and it mention about roles of Advanced SMEs and Data Engineers.  What is Advanced SME?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to know without a link to the original video, but it's likely a subject matter expert.

Azure Synapse Analytics is a very inclusive platform for various backgrounds and technologies in the Data & Analytics space. So to have a title of Synapse Engineer could be quite vague - this could mean that you're an expert at one or two techs within the platform, or that you're a jack-of-all-trades and master-of-none.

The idea of an Advanced SME within Synapse speaks to the possibility that an organization could have an SME for Spark Notebooks and another resource who is the SME for the SQL Pools or for Pipelines and Dataflows or something like that.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've worked with several of MS support staff on Azure Synapse and Azure Data Factory and their titles have been Azure Synapse Engineer or Advanced Support Engineer (ADF support reps have been Data Engineers), for what it's worth